# Issue with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have to submit a makefile for a project and I can't get it to work. I am trying to use the appropriate c++ 11 standard, execute project2,out, and run the cpp files in my src, but I keep getting the error **"Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'."**

```
#specify std=c++11 in your makefile
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

#Your executable should be named project2.out
main: g++ -o project2.out src/*.cpp

clean: del *.o
```

Comment: `g++ ...` should be on the line below (and indented 1 tab). And the same for `del *.o`.

Comment: I tried that and still got the same error. Am I supposed to use -c instead of -o maybe?

Comment: `project2.out` should be a target and `src/*.cpp` should be among its dependencies.

Comment: Also, if using terminal, it should be `rm *.o` not `del *.o`. Then try `make clean` before rebuilding to clear recently built flags.

Answer (score 1):

When asking questions please always *cut and paste* the **exact** command you typed and the exact output you got, properly formatted for SO (if you get a lot of output trim it down to the relevant parts which includes the command make invoked and at least the first few (not last!!) errors you get).

In this case, if you'd shown us what command you were running I'll bet it's this:

```
make Makefile
```

that's wrong.  The arguments to make are not the makefile to use: they're the target you want to update.  Here you've asked make to update your Makefile, but it already exists so make says "nothing to do".

Just run:

```
make
```

to build the default target, or `make clean` to build the `clean` target.

Once you get past this, you can begin to work on why your makefile may or may not work.

Comment: If you want to use a non-standard makefile with `make` you use the `-f` option like: `make -f someother.mk`